# How do you get the First Name, Last Name and Gender from Google Play Services AccountPicker (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, accountpicker

I'm using google play services AccountPicker.
My app doesn't require user to login but I added permission to get the account details in the manifest.

I would like to know the First Name, Last Name, email and gender of the user for push notifications (GCM)?

I'm using ANDROID STUDIO.

Thank you.

Comment: got any AccountPicker code to show?

Comment: Over here is a good tutorial on how to use Account Picker with Google Play Servives http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/google-play-services-setup.html